# ionic option select menu not working on IOS device

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm using the option select inputs inside a modal view for an app I'm working. For some reason when the select menu is displayed, it is done so without displaying the arrows and the 'done' button. It looks like this: [image: This isn't right]

It should look like this:
[image]

Comment: can try [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34067072/4302328) way

Answer (score 0):

Refer: [ionic-plugin-keyboard](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard)

Add code in:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function (FCMPlugin) {     
   cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);    
...
});
```